# How to change the font-size of an <a> tag after it's been visited?

Tags: css

I wanted to change the color and font size of the link after the link has been clicked and wrote the following code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        a:visited {
            color: green;
            font-size: 300px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://www.163.com" target="_blank">163</a>

</body>
```

The color changes but the font-size doesn't. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited)

> Note: For privacy reasons, browsers strictly limit the styles you can
>   apply using an element selected by this pseudo-class: only color,
>   background-color, border-color, border-bottom-color,
>   border-left-color, border-right-color, border-top-color,
>   outline-color, column-rule-color, fill and stroke. Note also that the
>   alpha component will be ignored: the alpha component of the
>   not-visited rule is used instead (except when the opacity is 0, in
>   that case the whole color is ignored, and the one of the not-visited
>   rule is used).
>
> Though the color can be changed, the method getComputedStyle will lie
>   and always give back the value of the non-visited color.
>
> For more information on the limitations and the motivation for them,
>   see Privacy and the :visited selector.

It's for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Font-size in :visited doesn't work in all modern browsers, but colour should do.  It's deliberate.

Generally, all colours will work, background-color, color, border-color, etc.

See here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the font size by using css :visited. It has a limit and the limits are

- color
- background-color
- border-color (and border-color for separate sides)
- outline color
- column-rule-color
- the color parts of fill and stroke

[read more](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp)

You can add a class to a visited link using javascript that will have a style with bigger font size.

The javascript solution https://jsfiddle.net/murtoza/2knq5uev/7/

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a").click(function(){
         $(this).addClass("visited");
       });
    });

a.visited {
        color: green;
        font-size: 300px;
    }
```